# How to install/use apache commons collection 4.4

Tags: java, import, apache-commons, fifo, netbeans-12

This is my first time using stackoverflow.

Anyway, I am trying to use the apache commons collections 4.4 that I've downloaded here
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi

This is the code that I am trying to run for you reference

```
import java.util.Queue;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.queue.CircularFifoQueue;
```

I am having trouble with my code as I need CircularFifoQueue to run my program. I'm using netbeans ide as of the moment and I would appreciate if you guys could share a solution that does not involve switching ide. Thank you!

Comment: You can convert your project into maven project (there should be an option in the context menu when you click on the project in netbeans) and then add apache collections as maven dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NetBeans project is Ant based you will need to add the jar you have downloaded as a Library.  In your project there is a Libraries folder that you can right-click and select Add Library.

If you are using Maven, you should add the dependency to your pom.xml file following Maven practices.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

If you are using Gradle (recommended) you should add a dependency using Gradle practices to the build.gradle file.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html#header

Comment: This solved what my problem. Thank you very much :)